# Слушатель клавиши мыши Python

Tags: python, мышь

Как слушать клавиши мыши на Python 3.6?
Я пробовал вот так, но не получилось, ничего не выводит:

```
from pynput import mouse


def on_release(key):
    pass


def on_click(key):
    print(key)


with mouse.Listener(
        on_press=on_click,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

UPD: Мне надо отследить конкретные нажатия на кнопку мыши, не положение мыши в этот момент. Причём не только Левой/правой/колёсика, но и дополнительных кнопок тоже.

Answer (score 3):

Мы можем установить "Low Level Hook" и обрабатывать все события мышки.

Вот вам небольшой пример, тут я реализую обработку не только событий мышки, но и клавиатуры:

```
print('__file__={0:<35} | __name__={1:<25} | __package__={2:<25}'.format(__file__,__name__,str(__package__)))
import ctypes
import win32con
import win32api
import win32gui
import atexit
from collections import namedtuple
import threading
import time
import queue

class InputListener:
    """
    https://gist.github.com/Amgarak/5df8477bad67dabbc491322e74ce1c2c
    
    Этот класс предназначен для прослушивания событий клавиатуры и мыши в среде Windows. 
    Он использует низкоуровневые хуки для перехвата событий, таких как нажатия клавиш, 
    отпускания клавиш, движения мыши и клики мышью. 
    Класс предоставляет функционал для регистрации обработчиков событий и фильтров, 
    что позволяет выполнять пользовательскую обработку событий. 
    Также поддерживается управление потоков параллельной обработки событий.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self.flagRun=False
        self.signal = queue.Queue()
        
        self._key_down = set()
        
        self.if_handlers = set()
        self.handlers = set()
        
        self.listener_queues = {}
        self.listeners =[]

        self.event_types = {
                    win32con.WM_KEYDOWN: 'key_down', # 0x100: 'key down', - WM_KeyDown for normal keys - 256
                    win32con.WM_KEYUP: 'key_up', # 0x101: 'key up', - WM_KeyUp for normal keys - 257 
                    0x104: 'key_down',  # WM_SYSKEYDOWN, used for Alt key - 260
                    0x105: 'key_up'}  # WM_SYSKEYUP, used for Alt key - 261
        
        self.mouse_types={
                    0x200: 'move', # WM_MOUSEMOVE - 512 
                    0x20A: 'wheel', # WM_MOUSEWHEEL - 522 - scan_code_top: 7864320; scan_code_bot: 4287102976
                    0x20E: 'H_wheel', # WM_MOUSEHWHEEL - 526 
                    0x204: 'key_down', # WM_RBUTTONDOWN - 516
                    0x205: 'key_up', # WM_RBUTTONUP - 517
                    0x201: 'key_down', # WM_LBUTTONDOWN - 513
                    0x202: 'key_up', # WM_LBUTTONUP - 514
                    0x207: 'key_down', # WM_MBUTTONDOWN - 519
                    0x208: 'key_up', # WM_MBUTTONUP - 520
                    0x20B: 'key_down', # WM_XBUTTONDOWN - 523 - scan_code: 131072; scan_code: 65536
                    0x20C: 'key_up'} # WM_XBUTTONUP - 524 - scan_code: 131072; scan_code: 65536

        self.mouse_key={
                    0x200: 'move',  
                    0x20A: 'wheel', 
                    7864320: 'wheel_top', 
                    4287102976: 'wheel_bot', 
                    0x20E: 'H_wheel',  
                    0x204: 'right', 
                    0x205: 'right', 
                    0x201: 'left', 
                    0x202: 'left', 
                    0x207: 'middle', 
                    0x208: 'middle', 
                    131072: 'X_Button_1', 
                    65536: 'X_Button_2'}       

        self.DeviceEvent = namedtuple('DeviceEvent', ['inputDevice', 'event_type', 'key_code', 'x', 'y', 'scan_code', 'key_down'])
        self.DeviceEvent.__new__.__defaults__ = (None, None, None, None, None, None, None)
        
        self.default_key = "Value not defined"
        
    def key_event(self, event):
        while not self.signal.empty():
            self.signal_handler(self.signal.get())

        for listener_name, listener_queue in self.listener_queues.items():
            listener_queue.put(event)
            
    def key_down(self, event_type, key_code):
        key = str(key_code)

        if key not in self._key_down and event_type == 'key_down':
            self._key_down.add(key)
            return True
        
        elif key in self._key_down and event_type == 'key_up':
            self._key_down.remove(key)
            return True
        
    def if_block(self, event):
        for if_handler in self.if_handlers:
            result = if_handler(event)
            if result is not None and not result:
                return False
        return True

    def keyboard_low_level_handler(self, nCode, wParam, lParam):
        lParam = ctypes.cast(lParam, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_ulong)).contents.value
        
        rezult = self.key_down(self.event_types[wParam], lParam)
        event = self.DeviceEvent('Keyboard', self.event_types[wParam], lParam, key_down=self._key_down)
        
        if rezult: # !!! - Отсекаем повторяющийся ивент key_down
            self.key_event(event)
        
        if self.if_block(event):   
            return ctypes.windll.user32.CallNextHookEx(self.keyboard_hook_id, nCode, wParam, lParam)
        else:
            return -1
               
    def mouse_low_level_handler(self, nCode, wParam, lParam):
        point = ctypes.cast(lParam, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_long * 2)).contents
        
        x = point[0]
        y = point[1]
        
        castomParam = self.mouse_key.get(lParam[1], self.default_key) if lParam[1] is not None else self.mouse_key[wParam]
        self.key_down(self.mouse_types[wParam], castomParam)
        
        event = self.DeviceEvent('Mouse', self.mouse_types[wParam], castomParam, x, y, lParam[1], self._key_down)
        self.key_event(event)
        
        if self.if_block(event):   
            return ctypes.windll.user32.CallNextHookEx(self.mouse_hook_id, nCode, wParam, lParam)
        else:
            return -1
    
    def listen(self):
        CMPFUNC = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p))
        ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExW.argtypes = (
            ctypes.c_int,
            CMPFUNC,
            ctypes.c_void_p,
            ctypes.c_uint
        )

        keyboard_pointer = CMPFUNC(self.keyboard_low_level_handler)
        self.keyboard_hook_id = ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExW(win32con.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyboard_pointer,
                                                                       win32api.GetModuleHandle(None), 0)

        mouse_pointer = CMPFUNC(self.mouse_low_level_handler)
        self.mouse_hook_id = ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExW(win32con.WH_MOUSE_LL, mouse_pointer,
                                                                    win32api.GetModuleHandle(None), 0)

        atexit.register(ctypes.windll.user32.UnhookWindowsHookEx, self.keyboard_hook_id)
        atexit.register(ctypes.windll.user32.UnhookWindowsHookEx, self.mouse_hook_id)

        win32gui.GetMessage(None, 0, 0)
        print(f"Hooks завершил свою работу..")
            
    def add_if_handler(self, func): # Регестрируем колбэк-фильтров
        self.if_handlers.add(func) 
            
    def add_handler(self, func): # Регестрируем колбэк-обработчиков
        self.handlers.add(func) 
        
    def remove_if_handler(self, func): # Удаление колбэк-фильтров
        self.if_handlers.discard(func) 
            
    def remove_handler(self, func): # Удаление колбэк-обработчиков
        self.handlers.discard(func) 
        
    def create_listener_queues(self):
        self.listener_queues = {func.__name__: queue.Queue() for func in self.handlers}
     
    def create_listener(self):        
        self.listeners = [
        threading.Thread(target=self.wrapper, args=(self.listener_queues[func.__name__], func), name=func.__name__)
        for func in self.handlers
    ]
        
    def start_listener(self):
        for listener_thread in self.listeners:
            listener_thread.daemon = True
            listener_thread.start()
      
    def wrapper(self, listener_queue, func):
        while True:
            event = listener_queue.get()
            if event is None:
                break
            func(event) 
            
        print(f"Демон {func.__name__} завершил свою работу..")
            
    def start(self, use_daemon = False):
        self.create_listener_queues()
        self.create_listener()
        self.start_listener()
        
        self.flagRun=True
        # Создаем новый поток и передаем в него функцию self.listen() - без скобок! 
        # Мы передаем саму функцию в качестве объекта. В этом случае, функция не вызывается немедленно.
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.listen, name="Hooks")
        thread.daemon = use_daemon # Включить при использовании GUI 
        thread.start() # Запускаем Hooks в отдельном потоке
        self.thread_id = thread.native_id # Получаем дескриптор потока, используя атрибут native_id объекта threading.Thread
   
    def stop(self): # Останавливаем слушатели\хуки
        for listener_name, listener_queue in self.listener_queues.items():
            listener_queue.put(None)
        
        self.flagRun=False
        ctypes.windll.user32.UnhookWindowsHookEx(self.keyboard_hook_id)
        ctypes.windll.user32.UnhookWindowsHookEx(self.mouse_hook_id)
        
        self.listener_queues.clear()
        self.listeners.clear()
        self._key_down.clear()
        
        user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
        WM_QUIT = 0x0012
        user32.PostThreadMessageW(self.thread_id, WM_QUIT, 0, 0) # Используя дискриптор потока, отправляем сообщение WM_QUIT 
                                                            # Для остановки win32gui.GetMessage(None, 0, 0)    

    def hot_removal_handler(self, func): # Горячее удаление колбэк-обработчиков
        signal = {"hot_removal_handler": func}
        self.signal.put(signal)
    
    def hot_plugging_handler(self, func):# Горячая регестрирация колбэк-обработчиков
        signal = {"hot_plugging_handler": func}
        self.signal.put(signal)
    
    def hot_removal_if_handler(self, func): # Горячее удаление колбэк-фильтров
        signal = {"hot_removal_if_handler": func}
        self.signal.put(signal)
    
    def hot_plugging_if_handler(self, func): # Горячая регестрирация колбэк-фильтров
        signal = {"hot_plugging_if_handler": func}
        self.signal.put(signal)

    def signal_handler(self, handler_dict):
        match handler_dict:
            case {"hot_removal_handler": func}:
                
                self.handlers.discard(func) 
                stop_signal_queue = self.listener_queues.get(func.__name__)
                stop_signal_queue.put(None)
                self.listener_queues.pop(func.__name__, None)
                print(f"Handling hot removal for function {func.__name__}")
                
            case {"hot_plugging_handler": func}:
                
                self.handlers.add(func) 
                self.listener_queues.update({func.__name__: queue.Queue()})
                listener_thread=threading.Thread(target=self.wrapper, args=(self.listener_queues[func.__name__], func), name=func.__name__)
                self.listeners.append(listener_thread)
                listener_thread.daemon = True
                listener_thread.start()
                print(f"Handling hot plugging for function {func.__name__}")
                
            case {"hot_removal_if_handler": func}:
                
                self.if_handlers.discard(func) 
                print(f"Handling conditional hot removal for function {func.__name__}")
                
            case {"hot_plugging_if_handler": func}:
                
                self.if_handlers.add(func) 
                print(f"Handling conditional hot plugging for function {func.__name__}")
                
            case _:
                print("Unknown case")
                
    def get_if_handlers(self, objekt=None):
        if objekt == "__name__":
            return set(if_handler.__name__ for if_handler in self.if_handlers)
        else:
             return self.if_handlers

    def get_handlers(self, objekt=None):
        if objekt == "__name__":
            return set(handler.__name__ for handler in self.handlers)
        else:
             return self.handlers

    def get_status_hooks(self):
        return self.flagRun

if __name__ == '__main__':

    log = True
    def print_event(event):

        if log:
            print(f"!-----------: \n"
                  f"{time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')} -> {event.inputDevice} -> {event.event_type} -> {event.key_code}\n"
                  f"X: {event.x}, Y: {event.y}, Scan_code: {event.scan_code}\n"
                  f"____________! \n")   
            
    def print_event2(event):

        if log: 
            print(f"!-----------: \n"
                  f"Нажатые кнопки: {event.key_down}\n"
                  f"____________! \n")
                
    def print_event3(event):     
        if log:   
            threads = threading.enumerate()
            thread_names = [thread.name for thread in threads]
            threads_str = ', '.join(thread_names)
            print(f"!-----------: \n"
                  f"Активные потоки: {threads_str}\n"
                  f"____________! \n") 
            
    def _if_block(event):     
        if event.key_code == 49:   
            print(f"Блокируем кнопку клавиатуры [1]")
            return False
            
    def _if2_block(event):     
        if event.key_code == "left":   
            print(f"Блокируем кнопку мыши [left]")
            return False

    def _if3_block(event):     
    # Проверка условия ограничения координат мыши
        if event.inputDevice == "Mouse" and 0 <= event.y <= 250:
            # Блокировка движения мыши
            win32api.SetCursorPos((event.x, 250))
            return False  # Блокировать обработку события мыши 

        if event.inputDevice == "Mouse" and 1000 <= event.y <= 1080:
            win32api.SetCursorPos((event.x, 1000))
            return False

    input_listener = InputListener()
    
    input_listener.add_handler(print_event)
    input_listener.add_handler(print_event2)
    input_listener.add_handler(print_event3)
    
    input_listener.add_if_handler(_if_block)
    input_listener.add_if_handler(_if2_block)
    input_listener.add_if_handler(_if3_block)
    
    input_listener.start()
    
    time.sleep(5)
    input_listener.stop()
    
    time.sleep(5)
    
    input_listener.remove_handler(print_event2) # Удаление колбэк-обработчика на холодную
    input_listener.remove_if_handler(_if3_block)
    
    input_listener.start()
    
    time.sleep(5)

    input_listener.hot_removal_if_handler(_if_block)
    input_listener.hot_removal_if_handler(_if2_block)
    
    input_listener.hot_plugging_if_handler(_if3_block)
    
    input_listener.hot_removal_handler(print_event)
    
    print(input_listener.get_handlers("__name__"))
    print(input_listener.get_handlers())
    
    print(input_listener.get_if_handlers("__name__"))
    print(input_listener.get_if_handlers())
    
    input_listener.hot_plugging_handler(print_event2)
    input_listener.hot_removal_handler(print_event2)
    
    time.sleep(5)
    
    input_listener.hot_plugging_handler(print_event)
    input_listener.hot_plugging_handler(print_event2)
    input_listener.hot_removal_if_handler(_if3_block)
```